# How is the embedded Tomcat behaviour in spring-boot-starter-web achieved?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, webserver

As the title states, I wonder how is spring-boot internally using Tomcat to serve requests, specifically, static files located in certain folders.

I am trying to create a war* archive that contains a deployable website and trying to get it to be as small as possible, since I only want it to serve static files, and I have managed the exact desired output with spring-boot-starter-web, but would like to rid myself of all unnecessary dependencies.

* (EDIT: as a side note, I have found out that making it a war archive is irrelevant since spring-boot is able to produce a jar under the exact same mechanism, but otherwise, they should function all the same)

However, I have been unable to find much (or really any) documentation on how this is achieved by spring-boot, not even by looking at the sources although I admit I am unfamiliar with spring-boot sources or non-boot spring projects in general.

I haven't found a way to actually start the same sort of behavior without the web starter

EDIT: For those wondering how the archive is created, here's a link to Spring's documentation on it: ["The Executable Jar Format"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)

Comment: if you want to serve only static content why do you need a web application, you can deploy your static content in a http server. you dont need a servlet container.
Look at this simple tutorial: https://dev.to/tikam02/deploying-static-website-in-apache24-1k63

Comment: why dont u try creating your won embedded tomcat app to understand better how it works? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: @techprat I am aware I don't need a web application, but I am interested in the ease it provides. All I need to do is hit package and spring-boot tooling will produce a web archive that can be immediately deployed anywhere with a JVM from a single file, serving my whole website. The concern for thinning out the dependencies is only because I know spring-boot will run other components automatically, and just a simple desire for a slightly more optimal solution. In short, I am using a servlet container because its easier to setup (spring-boot also provides default settings that work)

Comment: @JAsgarov I could create my own tomcat app, I even considered that. But as I mentioned in my other comment, I am interested in the help spring-boot provides to package everything as a simple web archive that can be deployed immediately anywhere with java, not setup or settings required

Comment: Tomcat can be embedded in a Java JAR-based project (no WAR is needed). Is that the piece of the jigsaw you are missing? Tomcat [provides](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=tomcat-embed) `embed-core`, `embed-jasper`, `embed-websocket`, etc. to support this. You can instantiate the embedded Tomcat process in your own code: `Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();` and so on. I don't know the specific details - but I assume Spring uses these Tomcat classes in its Spring-Boot-Starter-Web (for example).

Comment: "_I am trying to create a war archive_" - in other words, you don't create a WAR - you create a JAR to do this. See also frameworks such as [Javalin](https://javalin.io/), which do something similar. Javalin uses embedded Jetty, not embedded Tomcat. Maybe I have missed the point of your question?

Comment: @andrewJames Perhaps I haven't explained myself, spring-boot automatically creates a WAR archive that includes all dependencies, a custom class loader, alongside the build output, such that the archive is effectively a runnable java application. I am unsure why spring-boot packages as war and not jar, but in essence it's not different. Although I should perhaps look deeper into the Tomcat classes, since you make it sound like it would require little effort to create a similar setup with Tomcat alone

Comment: @andrewJames As per my other comments, the WAR is to all effects and purposes identical to a JAR, I am unsure why spring-boot packages the application as a war, but I can run it all the same through `java -jar archive.war`. In short, I was just wondering how does Spring achieve this behavior, in hopes of being able to just trim out the fat instead of having to replicate the behavior

Comment: This is what confuses me: "_spring-boot automatically creates a WAR_". Can you show how you are doing this? Maybe by editing your question? Spring Boot (for me) automatically creates a JAR, not a WAR, unless [I explicitly tell it to create a WAR](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy).

Comment: @andrewJames I actually just checked, funnily enough, I got confused reading the documentation and copied from the example for the war, under the impression that the jar option would produce a shaded jar, however, I just rechecked to source my claim and found out I completely misunderstood the article and both JAR and WAR can be used. However, the resulting archive is identical except for the folder containing compiled sources is BOOT-INF or WEB-INF depending on the packaging so jar or war shouldn't matter